# Android: Display Arabic text in TextView is not working on some devices

Tags: android, sqlite, fonts, textview, arabic

I have a problem in displaying arabic text in textview android. The arabic text is loaded from a sqlite file using cursor and I display it to textview. Here is my code in my custom cursor adapter:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c = cur;
    customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.context.getAssets(), "Fonts/qalammajeed.ttf");

    ListTerjemahanHolder holder = (ListTerjemahanHolder) view.getTag();

    //get text arab and convert from byte
    byte[] arabtext = c.getString(6).getBytes();
    String arabFull = "";
    try {
        arabFull = new String(arabtext, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.textArab.setText(arabFull);
    holder.textArab.setTypeface(customFont);

}
```

It displayed correctly on android phone devices like the screenshot in this link . [image]But when I tried on tablet emulators and tablet devices, it doesn't displayed correctly like this .[image] 
That tablet and phone devices are running in the same version of android 4.2.2 jelly bean.

I've already tried a lot of ways to display it correctly on most of devices using Farsi class, Better arabic reshaper, changing encoding types, etc but still not working. I also change the font to another fonts still display incorrectly on tablets, but no problem on phones.

I have a dead end here, please can anyone help me to solve my problem.. thanks..

Comment: have you designed the app compatible to all devices ???

Comment: Have you ensured that there is room for this text in your layout xml file?

Comment: You don't need to go through a byte array; `cursor.getString()` already returns a correctly encoded string.

Comment: Yes I already have a textview in xml. I already use getstring() without getbyte but still not display correctly, any other solution?

Comment: @DavidC Did you fix this?